# Wrapping content from WYSIWYG in div

Tags: java, liferay, freemarker

How would I wrap content (HTML) written in WYSIWYG (CKEditor) in div.

I have a variable ${SomePortlet.journalArticle.description}
e.g.

```
<div class="wysiwyg">${SomePortlet.journalArticle.description}</div>
```

is not the solution, because I need to wrap many elements in different portlets.

Is there any configuration option like 'wysiwyg editor output wrapper'? Thanks.

Comment: When do you want it to be wrapped in the DIV, when editing the text through the WYSIWYG editor, or when it's actully displayed on a page throught the Web Content Display portlet, or something else entirely? I little more context will be helpful.

Comment: When it's displayed on a page.

Comment: So how are you planning on displaying it? Through Web Content display or through a custom portlet?

Comment: So you just want to display some content that has been added through the Liferay WYSIWYG editor on a page in a DIV? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In DIV with class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To display the Liferay Journal Articles (i.e. information you've added through the Web Content WYSIWYG editor) in a div on a page you use the following:

```
<div class="yourCSSClass">
    <liferay-ui:journal-article articleId="${youPasstheArticleId}" groupId="${youPasstheGroupId}" />
</div>
```

Does this answer your question?